# Shut off screen on lid close?

Tags: power-management, laptop, 19.04

How can I tell Ubuntu to turn off the screen when I close my Laptop Lid?  I don't want to suspend the session, hibernate, or shut down. Simply turn off the screen.  AFAIK when I close it, the screen stays on as I can see some light peeking through.

I've tried [this suggestion](https://mensfeld.pl/2018/08/ubuntu-18-04-disable-screen-on-lid-close/) but nothing changed.

(From that above linked site):

> [To] Disable screen on lid close
>
> Copy-paste this into the terminal (as a root):

```
# sudo su
echo 'event=button/lid.*' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
echo 'action=/etc/acpi/lid.sh' | tee --append /etc/acpi/events/lm_lid
touch /etc/acpi/lid.sh
chmod +x /etc/acpi/lid.sh
```

> Edit the /etc/acpi/lid.sh file, paste following content and replace the your_username with your main user name:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
USER=your_username
 
grep -q close /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
 
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  su -c  "sleep 1 && xset -display :0.0 dpms force off" - $USER
fi
 
grep -q open /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
 
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
  su -c  "xset -display :0 dpms force on &> /tmp/screen.lid" - $USER
fi
```

If it matters, I'm running on a Dell Inspiron 15, with Ubuntu fully installed on an attached USB.

Comment: which ubuntu flavour are you running?

Comment: @cmak.fr 19.04 disco. (Does that answer your question? I'm new to Ubuntu so am not quite sure what you mean exactly)